# how to config name server in windows 2003 DNS

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, iis, vps, nameserver

I have a VPS with Windows 2003 installed on it and I want to create a dummy web server with DNS server based on my w2k3 server.

Here is what I've done:

1. Config my local gateway to my valid IP address.
2. Installing DNS server -> create a forward lookup zone for my domain lets say example.com
   and in the NameServer properties I have config two nameserver : ns1.example.com , ns2.example.com to the valid IP that they gave me.
3. Create "A" record for www.example.com
4. Installing IIS server -> create a website and add example.com and www.example.com to the header of website.

But still I don't get any proper answer from outside even by pinging ns1.example.com or www.example.com

Comment: Does www.example.com resolve correctly from outside and have you opened the right ports on your firewalls for your dns server to resolve correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don’t have your external DNS records setup and configured properly,
If you want to host the DNS and he web server  the root DNS for the domain must point to your DNS servers – you updated this with your registrar 
Then you need to have port (53) open in your firewall  and any translations needed setup.

It may be easier to just create the WWW record in your registrars DNS and allow them to host DNS for the domain.